# Automatically lock but not darken gnome shell when inactive

Tags: gnome-shell, screen-lock

Gnome Shell 3.8 can be configured to darken and eventually turn off the screen after a given period without user activity. (The corresponding setting can be found at `Settings/Performance`.) From there on, also after a configurable period of time, the desktop will be locked (forcing the user to enter the password to gain access). (This setting is to be found at `Settings/Privacy/Screen locking`.)

Now, I want to turn around this behaviour. After a few minutes, I want to be locked out, but the screen shall stay active for some minutes more. If possible, the screen could immediately blank when locked manually by the key combination `Ctrl+Shift+L`. Can this be accomplished with the settings panel? Or is it at least possible tweaking any underling settings?